# Populating a custom field every purchase IF there is a product that's back ordered within the order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We're using Shipstation for logistics and shipping coordination, and we're trying to create an automation that automatically puts orders that have a "back ordered" item in the "on hold" bucket.

You can pass custom field data from WooCommerce to Shipstation, I just can't figure out how to create a conditional Yes/No and population a field within Ship Station

A few articles to for reference:

WooCommerce > Shipstation Custom fields: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipstation-for-woocommerce/#section-8

Here is how it looks in Ship Station:

Filter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTLr3.png

Thank you!
Terence